# Error 1064 - MySQL Database Creation

Tags: mysql

So I'm a complete novice with MySQL and I'm trying to follow a tutorial that will allow me to sort out an Ajax + JQuery page for my database.

However, running this code in PHPMyAdmin:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'add_delete_record' (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'content' text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

produces the error:

> SQL query:
>
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  'add_delete_record'(
>
> 'id'INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  'content'TEXT NOT NULL ,
>   PRIMARY KEY (  'id' ) ) ENGINE = INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1
>   AUTO_INCREMENT =1 MySQL said:
>
> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''add_delete_record' (   'id' int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   'content' text' at line 1

Being a novice I have absolutely no clue what is wrong, apart from the fact that there is a problem with the syntax somewhere? Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks instead. Single quotes represent string literals.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_delete_record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

use backticks

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `add_delete_record` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `content` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Comment: Also needed for the column names.

Comment: @njk u was right i didnt see it , ijust saw near of `add_delete_record`, nice cought :), i didnt read the rest of code, ok no need to downvote me now :)